# Send a bitstream in an FPGA board

Tags: send, fpga, intel-fpga, bitstream, quartus

I need to be able to send bitstream in a FPGA board.

I use the Altera Cyclone III Development Board, I am looking for an option on Quartus for example to send bitstream, but I didn't find this either in the software nor on Internet.

Comment: Do you mean uploading a bitstream to a board or dynamic reconfiguration? Programing a board can be done by clicking onto "Program Device (Open Programer)". It's just below the synthesis 'buttons'.

Comment: Yes I would like to upload a bitstream, I need to send the bitstream of a video compressed to the FPGA board, and after process of the data (encoding & decoding), I recover the bitstream.

Comment: @Gilstaills I think you're using the wrong terminology here.  In the context of FPGAs a bitstream is a programming file for the FPGA.

Comment: You can use one of the interfaces available on your board (e.g. USB or eth) and send stream through some software application.

Comment: I found that it can be possible to create a programming file by converting a hex file where the bitstream is stored. Someone can confirms that it's possible ?